# How to do case insensitive RegEx in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a private method that I use for finding drug name using RegEx. The code is as following,

```
private boolean containsExactDrugName(String testString, String drugName) {

    int begin = -1;
    int end = -1;

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:" + drugName + ")\\b|\\S+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE).matcher(testString);
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

    while (m.find()) {
        results.add(m.group());
    }

    boolean found = results.contains(drugName);
    return found;
}
```

It should take a drug name and finds exact match inside the text String. That means if the drug name is `insuline` and the the String text is `The patient is taking insulineee for the treatment of diabetes`, it will break. It will need the exact match of `The patient is taking insuline for the treatment of diabetes`.

However, I also need case insensitive matches and if the text is `The patient is taking Insuline for the treatment of diabetes` or `The patient is taking INSULINE for the treatment of diabetes`, the method should return `true` as well.

I put the `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` inside the code, however, it doesn't work. How to write it properly ?

Comment: I do not understand why you need `\S+`. Look [here](https://ideone.com/9kZJNu), is the result expected?

Comment: That `|\\S+` looks very suspicious. It says "Or match any sequence of non-space characters".

Comment: If `insulineee` is inside the text, the return type needs to be `false`

Comment: Please check https://ideone.com/ekbweD where the check for a whole word is performed, and if it is in the string, it is split with whitespace.

Comment: Or if you just need true or false, see https://ideone.com/MxH730

Answer (score 5):

@Chaklader

Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE is the method I'm known to. It should work. 
for ASCII only case-insensitive matching

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("YOUR_REGEX GOES HERE", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

or for Unicode case-folding matching

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("YOUR_REGEX GOES HERE", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
```

Comment: check if you are using non ASCII characters.

Comment: This is the same what I use and still not working. I will report back after doing some more testing.

Comment: do a test of given method on a sample program and check for results. If Ok, then find problem in your actual program.